# Envers stopped auditing entity

Tags: spring, audit, hibernate-envers

I have ran into this issue: envers is not auditing anymore an entity that I have, although nothing changed.

All versions for hibernate and envers are the same ( i checked earlier ), and the entity is still marked as audited. 
The table is created and has some values, now there are no more entries added.

Has anyone dealt with it?

Comment: You might want to enable trace logging and see if that gives you any detail as to why you aren't seeing any records added.  Envers works on a before-transaction-completion hook so if no transaction is started or isn't being properly committed, that could be why.   Have you upgraded any jars such as spring recently when you started noticing the problem?